# When I try to add a deck of cards to my database i get: Integrity error decks_deck.cardID_id may not be NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: django

I made my models like this:

```
from django.db import models


class Attribute(models.Model):
    idAttr= models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description     

class CardType(models.Model):
    idCardType= models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class MonsterType(models.Model):
    idMonsterType= models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description 

class CardClass(models.Model):
    idCardClass= models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description 

class Card(models.Model):
    idCard= models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attrID= models.ForeignKey(Attribute)
    cardTypeID= models.ForeignKey(CardType, null=True, blank=True)
    monsterTypeID= models.ForeignKey(MonsterType, null=True, blank=True)
    cardClassID= models.ForeignKey(CardClass)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

class Deck(models.Model):
    idDeck= models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    cardID= models.ManyToManyField(Card)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

however when I fill in all the required fields in the database I get an error with the cardID saying it may not be null.

The Card class is used to add cards and the deck should show a list of all added cards throught the cardID field, which it does. I fill in all the other fields and select all the cards I want to add to the deck. But after clicking save i get the error mentioned above.

I've read various posts on this site and even read the djago documentation, but I haven't been able to solve it. I would appreciate all the help I could get.

Answer (score 0):

can you use this

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately that gives the same result.